# ORM-валидация для нескольких моделей (Kohana 3)

Tags: orm, php, kohana

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно в kohana3 провести валидацию данных, поступающих из формы для нескольких моделей.

Я использую метод, описанный здесь http://kohana3.ru/module/orm#проверка-нескольких-моделей-одновременно в результате получаю сообщение об ошибке, которое говорит о том, что используется несуществующий метод merge(). (смержить я их хочу для того чтобы массив ошибок не содержал ошибки или только первой модели, или только второй)

Так же пробовал проверять так:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Model_Checkcategory {

    public $error;

public function check($category, $title, $text, $active)
{

    $error = new ORM_Validation_Exception('', Validation::factory(array()));

    $menuL = ORM::factory('menuL');
    $page = ORM::factory('page');

    try
    {
        $menuL->title = $category;
        $menuL->active = $active;
        $menuL->check();
    }
    catch(ORM_Validation_Exception $e)
    {
        //$this->error = merge($e);
        //$this->error = $e->errors('validation');
        $this->error += $e->errors('validation');
    }

    try
    {
        $page->menuL_id = $menuL->pk();
        $page->title = $title;
        $page->content = $text;
        $page->check();
    }
    catch(ORM_Validation_Exception $e)
    {
        //$this->error = merge($e);
        //$this->error = $e->errors('validation');
        $this->error += $e->errors('validation');
    }

    $errors = $error->errors();
    if( ! $errors)
    {
        $menuL->save();
        $page->save();
        // Сохранение прошло успешно
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
       return FALSE;
    }
}

}
```

В результате получил в браузере сообщение об ошибке: `ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Unsupported operand types`

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как все-таки можно смержить массивы с сообщениями об ошибках для первой и второй модели? Или подскажите другой способ решения проблемы.

Вот [ссылка](http://prozaik.16mb.com/val/kohana_ART2.rar) на полный архив сайта, если интересно.

Answer (score 1):

А чем встроенные средства не устраивают? В каждой модели реализуй метод `rules()` и не парься. Вот тебе пример одной из моих моделек

```
class Model_Page extends ORM {

    protected $_table_name = "pages";
    protected $_primary_key = "page_id";


    public function rules() {
        return array(
            'page_id' => array(
                array('digit'),
            ),
            'alias' => array(
                array('not_empty'),
                array(array($this, 'aliasAvailable')),
                array('min_length', array(':value', 4)),
                array('max_length', array(':value', 1024)),
            ),
            'title' => array(
                array('not_empty'),
                array('min_length', array(':value', 4)),
                array('max_length', array(':value', 1024)),
            ),
            'text' => array(
                array('not_empty'),
            ),
            'date_create' => array(
                array('not_empty'),
                array('date'),
            ),
            'date_modif' => array(
                array('not_empty'),
                array('date'),
            ),
            'is_hide' => array(
                array('logical'),
            ),
            'is_deleted' => array(
                array('logical'),
            ),
        );
    }

    public function filters() {
        return array(
            'title' => array(
                array('trim'),
                array('strip_tags'),
            ),
            'alias' => array(
                array('trim'),
                array('strip_tags'),
            ),
            'text' => array(
                array('trim')
            ),
        );
    }



}
```

Когда пишешь

```
try{
    $model1->save(); 
    $model2->save();
} catch (ORM_Validation_Exception $e){}
```

Там всё и отлавливается

Comment: Я так пробовал уже. Не отлавливается. Если ошибка на этапе `$model2->save()`, то в таблицу, с которой работает модель 1 сохранение происходит, а в таблицу, с которой работает модель 2 - нет. То есть транзакция выполняется наполовину.

А правила `rules(), label(), filters()` в моих моделях прописаны. иначе как по вашему работает `$obj->check();` ?

Ваш совет не помог.